# Automate replace a lot content strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, string, replace

I have an string with HTML format, and I need to replace ALL the math exponents in HTML format `<sup></sup>`, to math exponents without HTML format.

I'm using the `replace()` method, but I need find and replace 100 exponents, from `<sup>1</sup>` to `<sup>100</sup>`, and I should write all the numbers (from 1 to 100).

```
var copiar = texto.
                replace(/<br>/g, "\n").
                replace(/<sup><\/sup>/g, "").
                replace(/<sup>2<\/sup>/g, "²").
                replace(/<sup>3<\/sup>/g, "³").
                replace(/<sup>4<\/sup>/g, "⁴").
                replace(/<sup>5<\/sup>/g, "⁵").
                replace(/<sup>6<\/sup>/g, "⁶").
                replace(/<sup>7<\/sup>/g, "⁷").
                replace(/<sup>8<\/sup>/g, "⁸").
                replace(/<sup>9<\/sup>/g, "⁹").
                replace(/<sup>10<\/sup>/g, "¹⁰");
                ...
                replace(/<sup>100<\/sup>/g, "¹⁰⁰");
```

My question is: **There is a way to automate this task?** Thanks!

**UPDATE**: I'm doing this replacements because I'm developing an App for iOS, capable to print (in HTML format) and copy to clipboard (plane text). That's the reason because I'm replacement the `<sup>` numbers.

**UPDATE 14/Oct/2014**: I was needing to replace negative exponents too. Using the @minitech answer and modifying a little, I could be able to replace ALL the exponents (positive and negative). Maybe can be useful for someone, here the code:

```
var map = '⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹';

var copiar = texto.replace(/<sup>(\-*(\d*))<\/sup>/g, function (str, digits){
    return Array.prototype.map.call(digits, function (digit) {
        var exp = "";

        if (digit != '-') {
            exp += map.charAt(digit);
        } else {
            exp += "¯";
        }
        return exp;
    }).join('');
});
```

Comment: Copying to clipboard as plain text is probably better done as `x^100` instead of `x¹⁰⁰`, though. I don’t know about your typefaces, but it looks bad in mine…

Comment: Thanks for your comment @minitech but that is the way I started my App, but how I manage large math expressions it doesn't look so clear. So I decide to change to this way `x¹⁰⁰`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A string and `charAt` provide a convenient way to map digits to the corresponding superscript digits:

```
var map = '⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹';

var copiar = texto.replace(/<sup>(\d*)<\/sup>/g, function (_, digits) {
    return Array.prototype.map.call(digits, function (digit) {
        return map.charAt(+digit);
    }).join('');
});
```

Comment: Your way is nicer than mine, it doesn't require hard-coding Unicode code points. But I learned some stuff writing mine :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really solve it, clean and wonderful! You're really good! ;)

Comment: @minitech there is a way to replace negative numbers too? Actually I'm needing this but I don't really understand the regExpr. Hope you can can help me!

Comment: @JabelMárquez: Do you have a superscript minus character you want to use?

Comment: @minitech Actually I think I fixed... I read about regExpr and debug the function (I did my best). I update my question and write the code I use if someone helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you do a replacement, you can supply a function to calculate it, instead of a fixed string. So you can use a pattern for all your `<sup>` replacements, and use a function that translates the number to Unicode superscripts.

```
var copiar = texto.
    replace(/<br>|<sup>(\d*)<\/sup>/g, function(match, digits) {
    if (match == "<br>") {
        return "\n";
    }
    // Rest is for translating superscripts to Unicode
    var superdigits = '';
    var zero = "0".charCodeAt(0);
    var superzero = 0x2070;
    var supertwo = 0x00b2;
    for (var i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
        var n = digits.charCodeAt(i) - zero;
        var char;
        switch (n) {
            // Superscripts 2 and 3 are at weird places in Unicode
            case 2: case 3:
                char = String.fromCharCode(n - 2 + supertwo);
                break;
            default:
                char = String.fromCharCode(n + superzero);
        }
        superdigits += char;
    }
    return superdigits;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I pick the minitech's answer because is cleaner and shorter. Thanks anyway, vote up for you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function get_sup_index(num) {
    var new_num = new String(num);
    new_num =   new_num.replace(/0/g, "⁰").
                        replace(/1/g, "¹").
                        replace(/2/g, "²").
                        replace(/3/g, "³").
                        replace(/4/g, "⁴").
                        replace(/5/g, "⁵").
                        replace(/6/g, "⁶").
                        replace(/7/g, "⁷").
                        replace(/8/g, "⁸").
                        replace(/9/g, "⁹");       
    return new_num;
}

var my_text =   '<sup>1</sup>'+
                '<sup>2</sup>'+
                '<sup>3</sup>'+
                '<sup>4</sup>'+
                '<sup>5</sup>'+
                '<sup>6</sup>'+
                '<sup>7</sup>'+
                '<sup>8</sup>'+
                '<sup>9</sup>'+
                '<sup>10</sup>';

alert(get_sup_index(my_text.replace(/<sup>([0-9]*)<\/sup>/g, "\$1")));
</script>
```

I hope that can help you.

Comment: I'm doing this "conversion" because I'm developing an App for iOS, with a possibility to print and copy to the clipboard. For print do it in HTML, but to copy do it plane. That's the reason.

Comment: I have edited my answer, I don't know if you will receive a notification for that. I am writing you just in case.